# Analysing a BlockingQueue usage example

Tags: java, multithreading, blockingqueue

I was looking at the "usage example based on a typical producer-consumer scenario" at:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#put(E)

Is the example correct?

I think the put and take operations need a lock on some resource before proceeding to modify the queue, but that is not happening here.

Also, had this been a Concurrent kind of a queue, the lack of locks would have been understandable since atomic operations on a concurrent queue do not need locks.

Comment: That's the great thing about most of the utilities in the java.util.concurrent package: you don't need to do the low level synchronization yourself.

Comment: I believe that only single atomic operations can be safely implemented this way. If we had a combination of these atomic operations, then we would still need external locks. In the above mentioned case, since the operations are atomic, one can get away without manually locking the resource. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think there is something to add to what is written in api:

> A Queue that additionally supports operations that wait for the queue to become non-empty when retrieving an element, and wait for space to become available in the queue when storing an element.
>
> BlockingQueue implementations are thread-safe. All queuing methods achieve their effects atomically using internal locks or other forms of concurrency control.

Answer (score 1):

BlockingQueue is just an interface. This implementation could be using synchronzed blocks, Lock or be lock-free. AFAIK most methods use Lock in the implementation.